# Notification is set immediately in Android

Tags: android, notifications

Call to method:

```
initNotificatie(endDate.getTime());
            Log.d("temp", "end: " + endDate.toGMTString()); // end: 13 Apr 2011 12:45:00 GMT
```

The method:

```
    public void initNotificatie(long when)      {
        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);


        int icon = R.drawable.herinnering_button_dropdown;
        String contentTitleString = getString(R.string.notification_title);
        String contentTekstString = getString(R.string.notification_tekst);
        CharSequence tickerText = "NotificationTekst";

        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);


        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence contentTitle = contentTitleString;
        CharSequence contentText = contentTekstString;
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MapDashboardActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
        final int HELLO_ID = 1;
        mNotificationManager.notify(HELLO_ID, notification);
}
```

How come this notification is set immediately while the notification is set for tomorrow? Is this because the notification constructor I'm using is deprecated? I can only use that one because I'm programming on level 4.

Comment: Check out the buzzbox sdk to easily schedule an event and create a notification. You can use a cron string for recurring events. http://hub.buzzbox.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `when` parameter refers to the time to be shown in the time field. It is not the time at which notification should be shown. In order to do that, use AlarmManager.